# What happens to image type when importing images in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, scikit-image, image-preprocessing

libraries such as PIL, Skimage and matplotlib mping all produced the same result

`img1 = io.imread("1.3/blurry-moon.tif")`

`img1 = img1.astype('int32')`

`img2 = io.imread("1.3/blurry-moon.tif")`

`imageArray = np.copy(img1)`

`image1 = np.copy(img1)`

`image2 = np.copy(img2)`

## applying a fir filter to these two images produces different results

`FIR = [[0, -1, 0],  [-1, 5 , -1],  [0, -1, 0]]`

## img1 produces an enhanced image while img2 loses some detail in darker regions

> 

[image: output of the two processes]

I don't understand why the imported image type by default produces such bad results, any ideas on what is going on?

Thank you.

complete code:

````
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import math
from skimage import io

# if current row of image exceeds row of convolutional filter, find the right row of the filter to apply
def convolve(image,filter, i, e):
  tot = 0
  for x in range(3):
      for v in range(3):   
        tot += image[i+x][e+v]*filter[x][v]
  return tot



# let img1 be an image with no features 
img1 = io.imread("1.3/blurry-moon.tif")
# change image encoding, keeps the source image as it is. What conversion happened when using the Library? 
# ***********************************
img1 = img1.astype('int32')


img2 = io.imread("1.3/blurry-moon.tif")

# These are their own individual new images
imageArray = np.copy(img1)
image1 = np.copy(img1)
image2 = np.copy(img2)

# gets the size of the image array
imageSize = imageArray.shape

FIR = [[0, -1, 0], 
      [-1, 5 , -1], 
      [0, -1, 0]]


for i, row in enumerate(imageArray):
      for e, value in enumerate(row):
        #   make sure we done apply the filter outside the image boundary
          if i < (imageSize[0]-3) and e < (imageSize[1]-3):
            image1[i+1][e+1] = convolve(imageArray, FIR, i ,e)

for i, row in enumerate(imageArray):
      for e, value in enumerate(row):
          if i < (imageSize[0]-3) and e < (imageSize[1]-3):
            image2[i+1][e+1] = convolve(imageArray, FIR, i ,e)


plt.imshow(img1, cmap='gray') 
plt.axis('off') 
plt.title('original') 
plt.show() 

plt.imshow(image1, cmap='gray') 
plt.axis('off') 
plt.title('Laplacian filter') 
plt.show() 

plt.imshow(image2, cmap='gray') 
plt.axis('off') 
plt.title('FIR filter') 
plt.show() ```
````

Comment: Looks like overflow/underflow to me. E.g. if your type is unsigned, a filter that could result in negative values will cause problems like this. But for a better answer, consider posting more complete code so we can reproduce your results exactly.

Comment: So the difference is that one image is int32 (signed) and the other is uint8 (unsigned, and small). In the uint8 image you get strange results when writing a negative value or a value larger than 255.

Comment: it is greyscale so values, negative or over 255 shouldn't be an issue